# apt-show-versions showing not installed packages with -r?

Tags: apt, package-management

As I've been using `apt-show-versions` through the years, it's always behaved such, that when using the `-r` switch/option:

```
   -r, --regex
       interpret package from option -p as a regex.
```

... it did NOT show packages that aren't installed; while if you wanted to list all packages, including uninstalled ones, you'd have to use `-R`:

```
   -R, --regex-all
       like --regex, but also show matching packages which are not installed
```

However, since I switched to Ubuntu 18.04, I've experienced that also `-r` starts listing uninstalled packages; for instance, this is what I get when I look up `linux` after a kernel upgrade:

```
$ apt-show-versions -r linux
binutils-i686-linux-gnu:amd64/bionic-updates 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04 uptodate
binutils-i686-linux-gnu:i386 not installed
binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu:amd64/bionic-updates 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04 uptodate
binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu:i386 not installed
console-setup-linux:all/bionic-updates 1.178ubuntu2.7 uptodate
libselinux1:amd64/bionic 2.7-2build2 uptodate
libselinux1:i386/bionic 2.7-2build2 uptodate
linux-base:all/bionic 4.5ubuntu1 uptodate
linux-firmware:all/bionic-security 1.173.2 uptodate
linux-generic:amd64/bionic-security 4.15.0.43.45 uptodate
linux-generic:i386 not installed
linux-headers-4.15.0-43:all/bionic-security 4.15.0-43.46 uptodate
linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic:amd64/bionic-security 4.15.0-43.46 uptodate
linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic:i386 not installed
linux-headers-generic:amd64/bionic-security 4.15.0.43.45 uptodate
linux-headers-generic:i386 not installed
linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic:amd64/bionic-security 4.15.0-43.46 uptodate
linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic:i386 not installed
linux-image-generic:amd64/bionic-security 4.15.0.43.45 uptodate
linux-image-generic:i386 not installed
linux-libc-dev:amd64/bionic-security 4.15.0-43.46 uptodate
linux-libc-dev:i386/bionic-security 4.15.0-43.46 uptodate
linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic:amd64/bionic-security 4.15.0-43.46 uptodate
linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic:i386 not installed
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-43-generic:amd64/bionic-security 4.15.0-43.46 uptodate
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-43-generic:i386 not installed
linux-sound-base:all/bionic 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5 uptodate
playonlinux:all/bionic 4.3.4 uptodate
pptp-linux:amd64/bionic 1.9.0+ds-2 uptodate
pptp-linux:i386 not installed
syslinux:amd64/bionic 3:6.03+dfsg1-2 uptodate
syslinux:i386 not installed
syslinux-common:all/bionic 3:6.03+dfsg1-2 uptodate
syslinux-legacy:amd64/bionic 2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu9 uptodate
syslinux-legacy:i386 not installed
util-linux:amd64/bionic-updates 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 uptodate
util-linux:i386 not installed
```

And the thing is, I had always used `apt-show-versions`, primarily to identify version numbers of *installed* linux kernels after a kernel upgrade, so I know what to remove.

Maybe the problem is that I also have i386 architecture enabled (since Ubuntu 18.04, there are no more 32-bit Ubuntu versions) - then again, I've had i386 and amd64 enabled in parallel before, and `apt-show-versions` didn't behave like this, to the best of my recollection.

So, would anyone know how to get `apt-show-versions -r` to behave as it used to - to show **only** installed packages? I really, really would not like to pipe into `grep` or something, to get the results I used to get so easily before....

Comment: Where is `apt-show-versions` from I don't even have it on my vanilla Ubuntu version!

Comment: Hi @GeorgeUdosen - it's not installed by default on vanilla Ubuntu, you have to do `sudo apt install apt-show-versions`